# A counter example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with a special property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then this sequence has a subsequence $(x_{p_n})_n$ such that $f(x+x_{p_n})$ converges to some constant $c_x$. We note that the subsequence $(x_{p_n})_n$ depends on $x$.

I am wendering if we can find a subsequence $(x_{p_n})_n$ that does not depend on $x$.

This led me to the following questions:

1) What is the nature of bounded continuous functions $f$ with the following property:

"Every sequence of numbers $(x_n)_n$ has a subsequence $(x_{p_n})_n$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$: $f(x+x_{p_n})$ converges to some constant $c_x$."

2) Can we find an example of a bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which does not have this property ?

---

We note (as mentioned by Jeff) that continuous functions with limits in $\pm\infty$ and continuous periodic functions have this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$ exist and are finite.

To see why, pick any sequence $x_n$. If the sequence is bounded, we can select a convergent subsequence, and then this works for any $x$. If the sequence is unbounded, then there must exist a subsequence converging to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Taking such a subsequence again works for any $x$, provided $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$ exist and are finite.

Comment: I think this property also holds for periodic functions.

Comment: Yes, periodic works as well. I only said the condition above is sufficient (not necessary).